# Is it possible to unload a kernel module without invoking its cleanup routine?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

Normally, if I use `rmmod` to remove a kernel module, the function specified by `module_exit` is run. Is there some way to `rmmod` **without having this function invoked**?

In case you're curious, the reason is that I have written and `insmod`'ed a module whose exit method is buggy and I'd prefer not to reboot the remote machine manually when it causes the kernel to hang.

I have looked at `man rmmod`, but it does not seem to have such an option.

Comment: well, not sure how to make it not call module_exit() each time you rmmmod but you can comment the code inside this function.

Comment: Clarification: The question is about removing an existing, compiled module without calling `module_exit()`, **not** about modifying the module so that `module_exit()` is **never** called.

Comment: In theory, you can use a kind of a hack: find struct module corresponding to your module in the kernel memory and set both 'init' and 'exit' fields to NULL there. This could be done with another kernel module. `rmmod` should not lead to calling of the cleanup function then. I would not recommend this hackish way though: what was allocated and otherwise initialized in init will remain there and that may lead to serious problems. @brokenfoot explained it right and clear.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to avoid unloading your module when `rmmod` is executed because there is some cleanup activity required when your module unloads, which if not done, you 'll not be able to reload your module again by executing `insmod`, as it will again call `module_init()` where you would have functions to registered (`alloc_chrdev_region()` or `register_chrdev()`) your driver. Re-registering it without un-registering it will result in a failure to load your module.

Comment: Indeed. Not to mention that the kernel may try to access these registered resources any time it wants to. And if the module is not longer present then, a crash is very likely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this does what you are asking, but the next time you recompile the kernel you can enable the MODULE_FORCE_UNLOAD option and try rmmod -f

https://lwn.net/Articles/15571/